# Matching sentences in the middle of a block of text until I hit 'Hello World'?

Tags: python, regex

So let's say I have this block of text, but I want to match the text before `HELLO WORLD`. What regex expression is appropriate?

I have used this: `Te pri\.[?=HELLO WORLD]` but nothing.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, timeam evertitur ex eos, utamur temporibus disputationi eum te. 
Te pri dicant exerci nonumy, in case erat albucius mei.  
Pertinax periculis concludaturque eum te, et nam vero nominavi deterruisset. HELLO WORLD. 
Ex augue scriptorem pri. Vocent minimum quaerendum duo eu, habemus adipiscing ex eum.
```

Keep in mind, I'm fairly new to Regex expressions.

Comment: `(?s)(.*?)HELLO WORLD` If you put it into an assertion, it gets matched the next time. Note that to be a real assertion it must be enclosed in a group construct `(?=)`.

Comment: In the above text, what exact text do you want to match before "HELLO WORLD"?

Comment: @nandal I want to match the text starting from`'Te pri dicant....'` until I reach HELLO WORLD. I don't want to include HELLO WORLD, by the way.

Comment: If there is no useful anchor I guess you have the beginning of the sentence itself. `(?s)Te pri.*?(?=HELLO WORLD)`

Comment: `Te pri\.[?=HELLO WORLD]` translated to English becomes: "Match the literal string 'Te pri' followed by a single dot. Then match one character from the following list: ?, =, H, E, L, O,  W, R, D"

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these expressions are matching my block of text:(

Comment: Hey all, I tried this `[^.]*Te pri.*?(?=HELLO WORLD)` and it worked. Thank you all for guiding me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want this regular expression:

```
(?s)(Te pri.*?)HELLO WORLD
```

Broken down, the pieces of the expression mean:

```
(?s)   -- Make the '.' regex metacharacter match newlines too
(      -- Start a capturing group
Te pri -- Match exactly 'Te pri'
.      -- The dot metacharacter matches any character except newlines
*      -- Match the prior metacharacter, character class or group zero or more times
       -- By default will match as many times as possible
?      -- When paired with '*', it makes '*' match as few times as possible
       -- This way, '.*' doesn't match 'HELLO WORLD'
)      -- End the capturing group
```

Access what is captured in the group using `.group()` eg.

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r"(?s)(Te pri.*?)HELLO WORLD")
m = regex.match(your_text)
m.group(1)
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:-

```
import re

text = '''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, timeam evertitur ex eos, utamur temporibus disputationi eum te. 
Te pri dicant exerci nonumy, in case erat albucius mei.  
Pertinax periculis concludaturque eum te, et nam vero nominavi deterruisset. HELLO WORLD. 
Ex augue scriptorem pri. Vocent minimum quaerendum duo eu, habemus adipiscing ex eu'''


try:
    foundSubString = re.search('(?s)(Te\spri\sdicant.*?)HELLO WORLD', text).group(1)
except AttributeError:
    foundSubString = '' # apply your error handling

print 'Match Found:',foundSubString
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is all characters `.` that appear one or more times `+`.

And you want to ensure that another pattern occurs afterwards without including it in the match, also known as a "positive lookahead" `(?=)`.

```
.+(?=HELLO WORLD)
```

[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/vZwObD/2)

If you want to match newline characters, you can simply expand the meaning of `.` by using the `s` flag/modifier.

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/ocizUa/3)